# Why SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween method does not return accurate result?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Hi I am working on computing distance from the nearest point of any route. I am testing 2 routes (polylines). The nearest point of the routes relative to the origin point is almost in the same coordinate or spot but SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween method of google maps android library returns very different results.

Example according to my code:

```
  for(Route route : routes){

        boolean isLocationOnEdge = PolyUtil.isLocationOnEdge(location, route.getLatLngCoordinates(), true, ROUTE_SEARCH_RADIUS);
        boolean isLocationOnPath = PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath(location, route.getLatLngCoordinates(), true,  ROUTE_SEARCH_RADIUS);

        if(isLocationOnEdge || isLocationOnPath){

            //meaning this route is near at the and compute distance from origin
            LatLng nearestPoint = findNearestPoint(location, route.getLatLngCoordinates());
            double distance = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(location, nearestPoint);
            Log.i(TAG, "origin: "+location);
            Log.i(TAG, "nearest point: "+nearestPoint); 
            Log.i(TAG, "distance: "+distance);
            route.setDistanceFromOrigin(distance);
            route.setNearestPointFromOrigin(nearestPoint);

            nearRoutes.add(route);
        }
    }
```

The result in the log is the following:

```
origin: lat/lng: (7.0792276,125.6248482)
nearest point: lat/lng: (7.079228237884086,125.6248559529709)
distance: 0.8584555298849629
origin: lat/lng: (7.0792276,125.6248482)
nearest point: lat/lng: (7.0792199725865546,125.62475406260717)
distance: 10.422383454451605
```

As you can see there is wide margin of difference among the two distances even though they have almost the same nearest point. (Please see emphasized comparison below)

### Route A

origin: lat/lng: (**7.0792276,125.6248482**)

nearest point: lat/lng: (**7.079228237884086,125.6248559529709**)

distance: **0.8584555298849629**

---

### Route B

origin: lat/lng: (**7.0792276,125.6248482**)

nearest point: lat/lng: (**7.0792199725865546,125.62475406260717**)

distance: **10.422383454451605**

---

To illustrate I plotted the polygons/routes and their nearest points with origin. I highlighted and indicated the distances base on the result that was logged by the code in the logcat. Why would the distance (red line) nearest point of **Route A** to origin would be just **0.8584555298849629** compared to the distance (green line) of **Route B** which is **10.422383454451605**? Base on the positions and coordinates of the nearest points they are close to each other therefore their distance should not differ greatly.

[image]

This is a bit confusing to me. Did I miss something or is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: What makes you think that these numbers are wrong? A difference of 10 meters is quite small.

Comment: @BenP. 10.42223 vs 0.8584? It is not small look closely almost 10 meters difference from the origin and considering both nearest point resides in almost same location.

Comment: I'm not intimately familiar with the location in question, but 10 meters is a very small difference in the grand scheme of things. Do you know for certain that these two points are *not* 10 meters apart?

Comment: @BenP. The scenario is I have 2 polygons/routes in the map and I have a reference point which is the origin now I managed to pinpoint the nearest points of both route in relation to the origin. As you can see both of the nearest point have almost the same coordinates meaning they are close together and should have almost the same distance to the origin yet the result of the method produces very different distances.

Comment: But you continue to not answer the question. When I put the two coordinates into a google map, I see one pin on one side of the road and one pin on the other side of the road. If that's a multiple lane road, it could easily be 10 meters between them. 10 meters just isn't that far.

Comment: @BenP. You didn't get the idea I am not looking for the distance between the 2 nearest points relative to the origin rather I am comparing the distance of origin to point A (nearest point of Route A) and distance of origin to point B (nearest point of Route B). Now their distances to origin should not deviate that much since they are quite close to each other. Almost 0 vs 10 is quite a difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150119/discussion-between-ben-p-and-ariel-magbanua).

Comment: @BenP. I updated my question/post please look at it to see what is the scenario is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no evidence that `SphericalUtil` is returning inaccurate information.

This map plots the origin and the two points you mention:

[image]

You can see the scale of the map at the bottom of the image. If that many pixels is five feet, then the two "nearest" points appear to be approximately 11 meters apart, which is exactly what your program output says.

Comment: You didn't get the idea I am not looking for the distance between the 2 nearest points,  rather I am comparing the distance of origin to point A (nearest point of Route A) and distance of origin to point B (nearest point of Route B). Now their distances to origin should not deviate that much since they are quite close to each other. Almost 0 vs 10 is quite a difference.

Comment: I updated my question/post please look at it to see what is the scenario is.

Comment: @ArielMagbanua The blue dot in your updated question is **not** at 7.0792276,125.6248482. Those coordinates are located at the differently-colored pin in my image above. See this map: https://www.google.com/maps/place/7%C2%B004'45.2%22N+125%C2%B037'29.5%22E/@7.0792291,125.6242325,18z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d7.0792276!4d125.6248482

Comment: I ran the app again that's the location provided by the listener and the position of the blue dot is the same as in the picture I provided. The blue is not the issue here but the distance between each nearest points to the blue dot (origin).

Comment: @ArielMagbanua Do you simply refuse to believe the google map link in the comment above?

Comment: @ArielMagbanua, the point (7.0792276,125.6248482) does not match what you provided in the update above. That point is situated between your two "nearest" points. Are you casting your origin point coordinates from a double to a float by chance?

Comment: @BenP.I double checked my code and locations. Looks like I misused some variables I forgot to use the current location of the user. I will try this tomorrow, thanks for your patience will accept this answer tomorrow after I test it. :)